# Model's scope function is showing wrong value, but only in production server

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm facing a weird problem which only happen in the production server (It's 100% normal in my local). I'm using Laravel 8, and have a model named `Student`. Inside the model, I created several scope methods like this:

```php
public function scopeWhereAlreadySubmitData($query)
{
    return $query->where('status_data_id', '!=', 1);
}

public function scopeWhereAlreadySubmitDocument($query)
{
    return $query->where('status_document_id', '!=', 1);
}
```

Then I use the methods above in an AJAX controller to chain it with `count` method. Something like:

```php
public function getAggregates()
{
    $student = Student::with(['something', 'somethingElse']);
    $count_student_already_submit_data = $student->whereAlreadySubmitData()->count();
    $count_student_already_submit_document = $student->whereAlreadySubmitDocument()->count();

    return compact('count_student_already_submit_data', 'count_student_already_submit_document');
}
```

Here's is where the weird thing happens: while the controller above produce the correct value in my local, in production `count_student_already_submit_data` has a correct value but `count_student_already_submit_document` has zero value. Seeing at the database directly, `count_student_already_submit_document` should have value more than zero as there are many records has `status_document_id` not equals to `1`.

I've also tried to use the `scopeWhereAlreadySubmitDocument` method in tinker. Both in local and production, it shows the correct value, not just zero.

Another thing to note is that `Student` model actually had 4 scope methods like the above, not just 2. 3 of them is working correctly, and only 1 is not. Plus, there's another controller using all the scope methods above and all of them are showing the correct value.

Have you ever face such thing? What could be the problem behind this? Your input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is because the query builder is effected by the given chain. The weird thing I mentioned about "local vs production" is likely doesn't gets noticed in the local because its only has a few records. I should've use `clone()` when chaining the builder. See the topic below for more information.

[Laravel query builder - re-use query with amended where statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30235551/laravel-query-builder-re-use-query-with-amended-where-statement)